# item level permission in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

if Item Level permission assigned to each item in sharepoint list, does it cause any performance issue or it has any limitation towards giving permission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has.

Microsoft does not recommend using more than 5000 unique permissions in a list in SP 2010, but you will have a performance impact even before:

> The throughput difference for operations on a list between 0 and 1,000
>   unique permissions is around 20 percent. There is a configurable
>   default of 50,000 unique permissions per list. However, we recommend
>   that you consider lowering this limit to 5,000 unique permissions and
>   for large lists consider using a design that uses as few unique
>   permissions as possible. This will help not only performance, but also
>   manageability

Source: https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/best-practices-for-unique-permissions-in-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: can you please provide more information on "5000 unique permissions in a list". does it mean like we can create groups or permission levels in SharePoint site not more than 5000, In my scenario, I have 5 group with all contribute permission and need restrict data so that data not related to particular group not get exposed via any means. Can you suggest any solution or item level permission will work out?